# Зафиксировать блок внутри кастомного скролла?

Tags: css, jquery

Есть блок с кастомным скроллом, внутри этого блока есть плашка, которая должна быть зафиксирована, причем снизу этого блока. К тому же ещё каким-то чудом, она не должна контент перекрывать когда сам блок скролится.

Есть какие-нибудь идеи хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться ?

ЗЫ. Плашка должна быть частью блока со скролом, если на нее навести и скролить, должен скролиться блок, а не вся страница.

https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/QPNybm

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">sticky</div>
  <div class="item">https://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/</div>
  <div class="item">https://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/</div>
  <div class="item">https://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/</div>
  <div class="item">https://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/</div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393378/4928642

Comment: этот вариант не подходит

Comment: А должен подходить.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//это просто что-бы нагенерить контент, ответ в css.
let appNode = '<div class="item">manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller</div>';
function generateNode (sel, appNode, qty = 1) {
  let $container = $(sel);
  for (let i = 1; i < qty; i++) {
    $container.append(appNode);
  }
}
generateNode('.container span', appNode, 20);
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px grey}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{height:5px;background-color:grey}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{width:10px;height:10px;background-color:green}
.container{height:150px;width:250px;border:1px solid black;overflow-y:scroll;position:relative}
.sticky{position:sticky;background-color:yellow;left:0;right:10px}
.sticky.top{top:0}
.sticky.bottom{bottom:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky top">sticky top</div>
  <span class=content></span>  
  <div class="sticky bottom">sticky bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но дело в том, что у меня нижняя часть всегда скрыта. Соответственно, нижняя плашка видно будет только когда мы вниз доскролим

Comment: ну так не фиксируйте её стилями, она будет снизу под всеми элементами.

Comment: так, а мне нужно, чтобы она была видна всегда. В этом и сложность, зафиксировать её к низу блока.

Comment: я вас не очень понял... в ответе нижняя "плашка" как раз прикреплена к низу блока. при прокрутке контента этого блока, обе плашки остаются на своих местах.

Comment: у меня в вопросе есть пример на codepen. Плашка sticky должна быть фиксирована в нижней части видимой области блока. Когда мы скролим блок, плашка внизу вместе с блоком скролится